# mysql order by issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

if i have a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE id IN (3,6,1,8,9);
```

this array of the ids is build in php dynamically ,
and the order is important to me.

```
$my_array =  array (3,6,1,8,9) ;
```

how can i sort the results by the order by which the elements appear in my array ?

its possible to do it in MYSQL query,
or i must to order it after via php ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can order by a value derived from a column. You can use a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) operator to specify the order:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN (3,6,1,8,9)
ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 3 THEN 1
                 WHEN 6 THEN 2
                 WHEN 1 THEN 3
                 WHEN 8 THEN 4
                 WHEN 9 THEN 5
         END
```

Comment: That's the answer I was thinking of - I had an edge case years ago that needed exactly this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested but this PHP solution should work:

```
<?php

$my_array =  array (3,6,1,8,9) ;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table  WHERE id IN (3,6,1,8,9)';

$sql .= "\nORDER BY CASE id\n";
foreach($my_array as $k => $v){
    $sql .= 'WHEN ' . $v . ' THEN ' . $k . "\n";
}
$sql .= 'END ';

echo $sql;

?>
```

This generates the following SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE id IN (3,6,1,8,9)
ORDER BY CASE id
WHEN 3 THEN 0
WHEN 6 THEN 1
WHEN 1 THEN 2
WHEN 8 THEN 3
WHEN 9 THEN 4
END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it this way you'll have to manipulate the data in PHP.  MySQL can only order by natural orderings ascending or descending.

Got to question though - why do you need the data returned in this very specific order?  There may be an easier solution to your problem by re-jigging something further up in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (3,6,1,8,9) ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,6,1,8,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the results into an array with IDs as indexes:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($l)) $items[$row['id']] = $row;
```

and then simply iterate it in your order

```
 foreach ($my_array as $id) { $current_row = $items[$id]; ... }
```