# Ordering by a prototype

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

There are 6 possible keys in a MySQL field. Lets call them types. Through PHP, I have defined an array, that is called $order, and arranges these types in order I want them to appear.

There is a table, `articles`, which has a field `articles`.`type` . Any article can have 0-6 types added to it. Now, what I want to do, is grab all of the articles, and order them from the prototype. What is the best way to do this? Can this be done in MySQL, since I suppose that would be faster? And if not, how can it be done in PHP?

Example:

Table:

```
id     articleId     type
1      3             type1
2      3             type2
3      3             type3
4      3             type4
5      4             type5
6      4             type6
7      5             type5
8      7             type1
9      7             type5
```

Order:

```
$order=array('type1','type2','type3','type4','type5','type6');
```

How do I fetch the results ordered by my `$order` variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175439/mysql-custom-sort might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to massage that array into a mysql-style if/case statement:

```
$order_by = "ORDER BY CASE";
$pos = 1;
foreach ($order as $clause) {
   $order_by .= " CASE `type`='$clause' THEN " . $pos++;
}
$order_by .= " ELSE " . $pos++;
```

which would generate something like

```
ORDER BY CASE
   WHEN `type`='type1' THEN 1
   WHEN 'type`='type2' THEN 2
   ...
   ELSE n
```

Comment: Nice. Will try it out tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be done in MySQL, since I suppose that would be faster?

Only if you allow MySQL to use an index

You can create a temp table:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
            sort INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (sort),
          KEY (`type`, sort)  
          ENGINE=MEMORY (SELECT 1,'other' <<-- see query below.
                   UNION SELECT 2,'type1' <<-- build this part using 
                   UNION SELECT 3,'type2' <<-- Marc B's code.
                   UNION SELECT 4,'type3'
                   UNION SELECT 5,'type4'   
                   UNION SELECT 6,'type5'
                   UNION SELECT 7,'type6' ";
```

Run this query.

Now you can link against this query using a join and use test.sort as your sortkey:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.article_id, COALESCE(t.`type`,'other') as sort_type
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN test t ON (t1.`type` = t.`type`)
WHERE ....
ORDER BY t.sort;
```

This query will be fully indexed and run as fast as possible.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this engine saves all of the data in the memory. What about power outages or restarts?

Comment: @janis It is just a temp table for the sort order you need to set it up when your code restarts if you want it permanent make it an innodb table

Comment: I read up on the temp tables, and it is now clear to me. Thanks!