# Sort WHERE IN SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony1, propel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql custom sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175439/mysql-custom-sort)

I have an array of IDs:

```
$ids = array(5, 1, 4, 2, 3);
```

and I make a query:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE id IN $ids
```

and I receive this object:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Is it possible to sort this same as in array? I would like receive

> 5, 1, 4, 2, 3.

I also use PROPEL. Maybe with Propel ORM in Symfony, is this possible?

Comment: one solution is to run the query in a foreach loop

Comment: @cristi_b: I think running one query is better than multiple ones.

Comment: you're right , forgot about usort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in mysql you can use the [field function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) for custom sort order. For example:

```
$ids = array(5, 1, 4, 2, 3);
$ids = implode(',', $ids);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons
        WHERE id IN ($ids)
        ORDER BY FIELD(id, $ids)";
```

Comment: I didn't know about `FIELD`.  Cool.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort it in PHP after you run the query.

Something like this (PHP 5.3+ only):

```
$ids = array(5, 1, 4, 2, 3);
// Run Query...
// assume $results is the result array
usort($results, function($a, $b) use($ids){
    $a = array_search($a['id'], $ids);
    $b = array_search($b['id'], $ids);
    return $a  -$b;
});
```