# Sort MySQL query by ascending value EXCEPT FOR 0

Tags: mysql, sorting, int

I'm making a task-management tool. Due dates of tasks are stored as a timestamp in a MySQL column called `dueTime` with a type of INT. If the task doesn't have a due date (many don't), the value of the dueTime column is 0. The tasks need to be displayed in order of **ascending** dueTime, with those without a due time appearing later on the list.

My current solution is `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE dueTime > 0 ORDER BY dueTime`, grab the data, and then run a second query of `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE dueTime = 0` and add that data next. It works fine, but I'd like to accomplish this with just one query. I also would rather not have to add an attribute of "has due time" since that seems unnecessary.

Other questions I've seen have involved using `GROUP BY`, but I wasn't sure if using that on timestamps, would be necessary or efficient.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: you can put a CASE statement in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: If you do `ORDER BY dueTime = 0, dueTime` the rows for which dueTime = 0 will sort after the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY dueDate IS NULL,dueTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have at least 3 possibilities:

- Don't use 0 as "no due time" but 99999, so you can keep your natural "ORDER BY dueTime ASC". (That isn't very clean...)
- Use two queries as you have already mentioned, and combine them with [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)
- Use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case.html) in your ORDER BY clause, as Randy has already mentioned. See also here: [mysql custom sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175439/mysql-custom-sort)