# MySQL Order by column = x, column asc?

Tags: mysql

I won't paste the whole query. It looks like this.

```
SELECT *, MONTH(date_created) as month 
from table 
GROUP BY month ORDER BY month='3', month asc
```

As it is April and I am querying this year I would have expected the order to be as follows 3, 1, 2, 4.

Instead I get out 1, 2, 4, 3.

How can I change the ORDER BY part of the statement to order the results by selected month first then the rest of months in the year showing sequentially?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175439/mysql-custom-sort

Comment: Please stop using `GROUP BY` like this. It's not ANSI standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `DESC`

```
ORDER BY month = '3' DESC, month asc
```

`month='3'` is a boolean expression which returns 1 or 0, so basically when the result is zero, it will on the last part of the result.

or without using `DESC`, use `<>`

```
ORDER BY month <> '3', month asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `DESC` or `ASC` in the first order :

```
SELECT *, MONTH(date_created) as month 
FROM table 
GROUP BY month ORDER BY month='3' DESC, month ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution is ORDER BY FIELD

```
SELECT * FROM table
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY FIELD(month, 3,1,2,4)
```