# Sort by two columns with conditionals?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table with a column `priority_n`. Pretend there are 5 items in that table. Two with `nil` as `priority_n`, and the other three have `1`, `2`, `3`.

I'd like to do a `where(priority_n: nil).order(published_at: :desc)` combined with `where.not(priority_n: nil).order(priority_n: :asc)`. I want the `nil` ones at the beginning of the active record relations, and then the prioritized ones after them. Is there a way to do this?

If I could figure out how to do this in SQL then I could do it in rails.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the `order by` clause in standard SQL:

```
order by (case when priority_n is null then 0 else 1 end),
         priority_n asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Case statements will not make efficient use of indexes.

```
ORDER BY priority_N IS NULL DESC, priorit_n ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In **PostgreSQL**, sorting nulls first / last is dead simple with the (standard SQL!) `NULLS FIRST | LAST`:

```
ORDER BY priority_n NULLS FIRST, published_at
```

The second `ORDER BY` item, because it seems you want to order rows with the same `priority_n` according to `published_at`.

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- [ORDER BY DATE showing NULLS first then most recent dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821798/order-by-date-showing-nulls-first-then-most-recent-dates)

**MySQL** does not implement `NULLS FIRST | LAST`. Substitute with:

```
ORDER BY priority_n IS NOT NULL, priority_n, published_at
```

Would work in Postgres, too.
`priority_n IS NOT NULL` is a boolean expression that evaluates to `FALSE` (`0`) or `TRUE` (`1`). `0` sorts before `1` (and both before `NULL`, but not relevant here.), so rows with `priority_n IS NULL` come first.

- [ORDER BY ASC with Nulls at the Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993109/order-by-asc-with-nulls-at-the-bottom)
- [MySQL Order by column = x, column asc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216773/mysql-order-by-column-x-column-asc/16216810#16216810)