# Sorting after union all or order by case when

Tags: php, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

To test these queries I’m running them in the SQL query wizard in Microsoft Access. I’m trying to modify an existing php file in order to display the high priority status alerts (O and P) at the top which are then ordered by opslogid in a descending order. After there are no more O and P status alerts I want to display the rest of the status alerts (A, I, R), ordered by opslogid in a descending order. This is the sample data and required output:

**tblOpslog**

```
opslogid = 9999, 9998, etc.

status = R, O, I, A, P

opslogid                               status

9999                                       P

9996                                       P

9994                                       O

9991                                       O

9998                                       I

9997                                       I

9980                                       A

9979                                       A

9978                                       A

9930                                       R

9928                                       R
```

My colleague suggested that i used the union all command, which resulted in me coming up with this:

**NOTE:** THE “`WHERE DELETED AND NO VIEW MUST REMAIN IN QUERY, IT IS VITAL IN THE OUTPUT OF THE DATABASE`”. ALSO I CANNOT MAKE ANY CHANGES TO THE DATABASE ITSELF.

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM tblOpslog
Where Deleted = No AND Noview = No AND status in ('O','P'))
union all
select * from (Select * FROM tblOpslog Where Deleted = No AND Noview = No AND status in ('I','R', 'A'))
Order by status, opslogid DESC;
```

The output of this is:

```
opslogid                               status

9980                                       A

9979                                       A

9978                                       A

9998                                       I

9997                                       I

9994                                       O

9991                                       O

9999                                       P

9996                                       P

9930                                       R

9928                                       R
```

I have also tried this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblOpsLog
WHERE Deleted = No AND Noview = No AND status IN ('A', 'I', 'R', 'O', 'P')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN status IN ('O', 'P') then 1
              ELSE 2
         END, opslogid DESC
```

Which has given me this error:

```
Syntax error (missing oeprator) in query expression 'CASE WHEN status IN ('O','P') then 1 ELSE 2 End'.
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can someone suggest what to fix/add to the code to display the desired output? Thank you

Comment: Check out this one on how to apply custom sort order for your Priority letters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175439/mysql-custom-sort Then just use one single select ordered by priority and then id. Not sure on performance though...

Comment: Does microsoft access support the Case When statement? It's giving me an error.  Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Are you going to be using MS Access with your php file? If not, then can you test against the database you will be using, rather than worrying about why your tests don't work? As a complete guess, have you tried putting brackets around the CASE? I.e. `SELECT ... ORDER BY (CASE ... END), opslogid DESC` - I have no reason to expect this to work, but it's something I would try.

Comment: Yeah I did try putting brackets around the Case still no luck.

Comment: And yes I will be using MS Access with my php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Access which doesn't support the `case` statement.  Try this version using Access syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblOpsLog
WHERE Deleted = No AND Noview = No AND status IN ('A', 'I', 'R', 'O', 'P')
ORDER BY iif(status IN ('O', 'P'), 1, 2),
         opslogid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblOpsLog WHERE Deleted = No AND Noview = No 
AND status IN ('A', 'I', 'R', 'O', 'P')
ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 'P' then 1
WHEN 'O' then 1
ELSE 2
END, opslogid DESC
```

Comment: It gives me this error:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Case status WHEN 'P' then 1 WHEN 'O' then 1 ELSE 2 END'.

Comment: Please note I'm running this sql query using microsoft access' database so there might be some limitations.  Is there any way to get around this?